# AJax is not a function error

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I'm trying to perform a simple `$.ajax` call to giphy and I keep getting  the following error:

> index.html:32 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Below is the exact code I'm running. What is going on?

```
<button id="duckbtn">Duck Button</button>
<div id="images"></div>
<div id="ratings"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#duckbtn').on("click", function(){

    var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&tag=cats";

    $.ajax({
      url: queryURL,
      method: "GET"
    })
    .done(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: jquery is not included.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using slim version of jQuery. It Doesn't support ajax Calling. Use following cdn or download full version of jquery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/santosh_singh/uhm459mj/2/)**

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: I'm new to Stack overflow,  how can I send the code?

Comment: @santoshsingh: dont forget to check his document ready function. because this commonly happen when jquery still load/downloading, but ajax was called first. good luck

Comment: @GabePerry you can use pastebin.com

Comment: @plonknimbuzz :)

Comment: you can create jsfiddle and share the url

Comment: I am able to see the response in jsfiddle

Comment: where are you seeing the response_?

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Before all other JavaScript includes, and before `bootstrap.js` or any other plugins are included.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uhm459mj/ all I did in the HTML section was at the very top I added this `script`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

And it started working, all you were missing was the `jQuery`